# How do I start using source control with an existing project?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, github, atlassian-sourcetree

So I'm working on my first website in Eclipse. It is very simple only shows some text and an input box currently that does nothing, all this eclipse stuff is in my project folder. I've set it up to use Apache Tomcat 9 which is also in my project folder.

Now I think that I shouldn't just push my top level project folder as if I do this, everytime I open up the project in Eclipse, Sourcetree will show 50 or so files modified (.metadata files and such), so I'm guessing that I shouldn't have pushed these to start with.

I've since reset all my commits and am now wondering which files are necessary to upload to github?

Answer (score 0):

You should add all source files to git: the actual code that runs your site (PHP, JavaScript, HTML, whatever it is), along with things like CSS. Don't include config files or files auto generated by the IDE (Eclipse in your case). You can use a `.gitignore` file to tell git not to pay attention to certain files, types of files, or directories. [A guide to .gitignore files can be found here.](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: Can you specify the contents of your gitignore and the git commands you use and the errors you get? @Aequitas

Comment: @NiklasP I think I've got it working, seems to need .project and .class files as well. I wasn't getting an error just nothing would happen when I clicked import